# How to add custom resolvers to Apollo Gateway?

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have an Apollo GraphQL gateway which sits in front of 2 federated subgraphs.

I want to be able to add a custom resolver to my gateway so that I can call subgraph A and then call subgraph B with the response.

For example a resolver that does the following:

```
// gateway 
const gateway = new ApolloGateway({
  serviceList: [
    { name: 'products', url: 'https://products-service.dev/graphql' },
    { name: 'reviews', url: 'https://reviews-service.dev/graphql' }
  ],
  introspectionHeaders: {
    Authorization: 'Bearer abc123'
  }
});

// mutation resolver 
doSomeThing: () => {
  // retrieve product data from product service 

  // send request to review service
}
```

This is just a basic example but it is my understanding that the gateway should be the orchestration layer and should handle calling one service and then another.

Do I need to just handle this like a regular resolver and use some fetch library to call the subgraphs?

Is there a way to tap into the predefined subgraphs configured in my gateway and make a GraphQL request?

Comment: Have you found an answer to that? or maybe a workaround?

Comment: No I haven't. Spoke to someone at Apollo who didn't seem to have a solution here either.

Comment: It would seem you would have to setup your GraphQL Gateway on top of all your subgraphs which acts as a proxy. I am now looking at creating a backend for frontend (https://medium.com/mobilepeople/backend-for-frontend-pattern-why-you-need-to-know-it-46f94ce420b0) to handle the orchestration. Annoyingly, if I ever have a second client for my app, I would have to replicate all that orchestration logic in another backend for frontend which is not ideal but seems like the only way.

Comment: I guess GraphQL solves most of the items that the BFF has to solve, so I wouldn't want to build BFF in my case... Will continue investigating the topic and see what we can do here.